# Webjar not resolving in angular-seed-play project

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.0, requirejs, webjars

I'm using the angular-seed-play at the moment which has been very handy but am having problems configuring more angular dependencies.

I want to use Angular UI Bootstrap but it's not working for me.

My app.js is essentially

```
define('angular', ['webjars!angular-locale_en-gb.js'], function() {
    return angular;
});

require(['angular', './controllers', './directives', './filters', './services', 'webjars!angular-ui.js'],

function(angular, controllers) {
    angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  ....
}]);
```

This result in

```
Uncaught No WebJar dependency found for angular-ui-bootstrap. Please ensure that this is a valid dependency
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the dependency is missing? `angular-ui-bootstrap` is separate from AngularJS. In your **Build.scala**, add the following and then run `play update`:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
 ...,
 "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "0.3.0-1" exclude("org.webjars", "angularjs")
)
```

**app.js**:

```
require(['angular', './controllers', './directives', './filters', './services', "webjars!ui-bootstrap.js", "webjars!ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"], function(angular, controllers, directives, filters, services) {
  angular.module("your.module", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.tpls"]);
}
```

Comment: Definitely needed the dependency. Also changed the require to     "require(['angular', './controllers', './directives', './filters', './services', 'webjars!ui-bootstrap-tpls'],". Thanks!

Comment: Right, I added that to the answer.